# Extent report in cucumber showing gherkin keyword twice i.e. Given ,When Then

Tags: cucumber, testng, reporting, extentreports

[image]Extent Reports with cucumber plugin showing the Gherkin keyword two time per step

Feature: LinkedIn sign up 
    I want to use this template for my feature file

@nimit 
Scenario Outline: To verify LinkedIn site is up and running 
    Given Environment is up to verify LinkedIn site using TestData ""
    When User navigate to LinkedHome Page
    Then Welcome page should displayed to user
    Then 'Join Now & Sign in' button should be displayed
    Examples: 
        |Testdataset|
        |SCN1#TD1|

public class LinkedSignupScenarios {

```
  LinkedInSignupPage page = new LinkedInSignupPage();

    @Given("^Environment is up to verify LinkedIn site using TestData \"([^\"]*)\"$")
    public void InitiateTest(String Testdata) {
        System.out.println("===User setup environment");
        page.createTest(Testdata, "LinkedInSignupTestData");
    }

    @When("^User navigate to LinkedHome Page$")
    public void navigateTo() {
        Assert.assertThat("Validate navigation",true,is(page.navigate("url")));
    }

    @Then("^Welcome page should displayed to user$")
    public void isWelcomePageDisplayed() {
        Assert.assertThat("Validation for Welcome Page",
                true,
                is(page.isPagedisplayed("PageTitle","Linkedin.Heading")));
    }

    @Then("^'Join Now & Sign in' button should be displayed$")
    public void join_Now_Sign_in_button_should_be_displayed() throws Throwable {
        Assert.assertThat("Validation for Join Now link",
                true,
                is(page.isPresent("Linkedin.JoinNow"))); 
    }
```

}

Comment: My guess is that your code is erroneously something like: `@Given("Given Environment...")`  If not, show your feature file and steps file

Comment: Thanks for the reply but the case is not that .... I am attaching the feature and steps file                       
==============================

Comment: Who's plug-in for Extent Reports are you using, and how does your runner class look?  Please add that as well.  At first glance, it looks like your steps and maybe your features are correct, but your features are not formatted so I'm only guessing at that.

Comment: @RunWith(Cucumber.class)
@CucumberOptions(
features = "Features"
,glue={""},
plugin = {"com.cucumber.listener.ExtentCucumberFormatter:Reports/cucumber-report.html"}
//tags= {"@nimit"}
)public class CucumberTest extends AbstractTestNGCucumberTests {
 
 Harness harness = new Harness();
 
 @BeforeTest
 @Parameters("browser")
 public void createdriver(String browser) {
  harness.intiateDriver(browser);
 }
 
 
}

Comment: Got it working by upgrading the extent reports version

Answer (score 0):

Got it working by upgrading the extent reports version